# How to Export SolidWorks file to use in WebGL?

Tags: webgl, solidworks

Is there a way to export or convert a SolidWorks file to be used in any way for WebGL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you want to go with this, but http://showwebgl.com/ (see http://plopbyte.net/2011/04/showwebgl/ for a brief description) will upload and display models in a variety of formats, and uses a WebGL framework called ogs.js.  So you just need to convert your SolidWorks file to one of those.

A lot of WebGL frameworks accept Collada format.  If you can't track these down, let me know.

Comment: My goal is to build 3d models in SolidWorks and display/control them with JS on a webpage. The important part of your answer is that some WebGL frameworks accept Collada format. This plugin should export Collada to SolidWorks: http://labs.solidworks.com/Products/Product.aspx?name=colladaexport ... will try it and post results here. Planning to use the scenejs.org framework to display the collada file.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://resouces.publishyourdesign.com.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/SolidworksPlugin_x64.zip) is a Solidworks plugin which can export Solidworks models to a lightweight visualization format .pyd. [This site](http://www.publishyourdesign.com/) has a webgl based pyd viewer to view published pyd file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Collada export from the SolidWorks labs page. But you should consider simplifying your models before exporting them to Collada with a tool like Swap3D. This will decrease filesize dramatically. Export to Collada works much better when exporting a part instead of an assembly. So you should always consider saving an assembly as part.

Comment: I find the Collada export plug-in for SolidWorks extremely buggy and on top of that many people complain not to be able to install it at all. My advice is to do the following - export your model in VRML (or STL). Yes, you loose most of the quality but at least VRML is well supported by SolidWorks (and many other applications that are used for 3d modeling/CAD-design). Collada supports external file linkage and thus you can call your VRML files from a Collada-file or even import all the data by copying it. See the OpenRAVE Collada writer. It's as far as I know the best Collada exporter.